# Single legend when plotting on secondary y-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, legend

I have the following code to plot the data of a Pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

plt.figure()
plt.title('Title')

ax1 = df.R.plot(style='b', label='Suc. Rate')
ax1.set_ylabel('Success Rate / Coherence')

ax2 = df.C.plot(style='r', label='Coherence')

ax3 = df.S.plot(secondary_y=True, style='g', label='Size')
ax3.set_ylabel('Lexicon Size')

plt.legend()
```

The plots are correct, but only the last line with label `Size` is shown in the legend. How can I get all 3 lines in a single legend?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to get the legend `handles` and `labels` from each `Axes`, and then pass lists of all the handles and labels to legends. You can use [`ax.get_legend_handles_labels()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_legend_handles_labels) to do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Some sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'C' : [4,5,6,7], 'S' : [10,20,30,40],'R' : [100,50,-30,-50]})

fig=plt.figure()
plt.title('Title')

ax1 = df.R.plot(style='b', label='Suc. Rate')
ax1.set_ylabel('Success Rate / Coherence')

ax2 = df.C.plot(style='r', label='Coherence')

ax3 = df.S.plot(secondary_y=True, style='g', label='Size')
ax3.set_ylabel('Lexicon Size')

handles,labels = [],[]
for ax in fig.axes:
    for h,l in zip(*ax.get_legend_handles_labels()):
        handles.append(h)
        labels.append(l)

plt.legend(handles,labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: There are a lot of possible answers for this question, but this one is by far the most easy to implement and the one I always choose to use when plotting with more than one axis